# Помогите выставить изображение баннера во всю ширину

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, выставить баннер на [главной странице](http://ukraina.market/) во всю ширину.

Что бы не было отступов по бокам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя не получется потому что у родительского элемента выставлен **padding** (отступы) в твоем случае:

```
<div class="container-fluid  content-grid">
```

Перенеси

```
<div class="row-fluid ">                <div class="span16 " >
            <div class=" amaz_banner">
    <div class="ty-wysiwyg-content" ><img src="http://ukraina.market/images/promo/24/ftvs-sweats_1500x300-unrec._CB276087541_.jpg"></div>
</div>
    </div>
```

этот участок на пару строк вверх чтобы он был выше блока с отступами

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо убрать `padding` в блоке `div`, где располагается баннер. Потом можно самому блоку с баннером задать стиль `width: 100%;`.